# Alchemy Mumbai endpoint not working from truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, testnets, polygon, alchemy

I am trying to deploy some smart contracts on Mumbai network from truffle using an Alchemy endpoint I just created.

this is my truffle-config.js

[image]

But I am getting errors all the time :

[image]

Not to long ago I used to interact with the first endpoint (https://matic-mumbai.chainstacklabs.com") but it stopped working with "TIMEOUT" errors, that is why I subscribed for an alchemy endpoint, but it is not helping me much either....

Has anyone already faced the same issue?